# Find out source of raised Routed Event

Tags: wpf, events, routed

I've small trouble. I don't know why my controls firing events twice. I know it was discussed few times on stackOverflow, but still i cannot find out cause.

Is there any way to debug application and find what is the main cause of raised event? I'm not good at (at this moment) profiling, but mayby it's the good path.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you wait for a more definitive answer, check that you haven't added the event handler twice.